# Rotating towards mouse in C# is not working correctly

Tags: c#, rotation, mouse

I am trying to have an object rotate towards the mouse.
The problem is that the object always rotates a bit to much to the left, an extra 45 degrees to much to be excact.

So for example if my mouse is at such a position that the object should be positioned to the north, thus the rotation value = 0, the object gets rotatated 45 degrees to the left, so 270 degrees and thus pointing left, while it should point north/upwards.

This is my code:

```
    public override void Update()
    {
        base.Update();

        GetMousePos();
        SetRotation();
    }

    private void GetMousePos()
    {
        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();
        _mousePos.X = ms.X;
        _mousePos.Y = ms.Y;
    }

    private void SetRotation()
    {
        Vector2 distance = new Vector2();
        distance.X = _mousePos.X - (_position.X + (_texture.Width / 2));
        distance.Y = _mousePos.Y - (_position.Y + (_texture.Height / 2));
        _rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(distance.Y, distance.X);
    }
```

**EDIT: extra info**

These values appear when my mouse is in the right side of the screen. The object should point east/right, but he points north/upwards.

MOUSE POS X: 1012

MOUSE POS Y: 265

OBJECT POS X: 400275

OBJECT POS Y: 24025

ROTATION: 0

**EDIT 2: how _rotation is used**

```
public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        int width = _texture.Width / _columns;
        int height = _texture.Height / _rows;

        Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle((int)_position.X, (int)_position.Y, width, height);
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle((int)((_texture.Width / _columns) * _currentFrame), 0, width, height);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, destinationRectangle, sourceRectangle, Color.White, _rotation, new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

**EDIT 3: The working fix thingy**

```
    protected void SetRotation()
    {
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(mouse.X, mouse.Y);

        Vector2 direction = mousePosition - _position;
        direction.Normalize();

        _rotation = (float)Math.Atan2(
                      (double)direction.Y,
                      (double)direction.X) + 1.5f;
    }
```

Comment: Post the value of `_rotation` for us and the _mousePos.X and _mousePos.Y values.

Comment: Seems like a math problem more than a code problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, I added the data you requested

Answer (score 2):

Look at the docs for `Math.Atan2`:

> The return value is the angle in the Cartesian plane formed by the x-axis, and a vector starting from the origin, (0,0), and terminating at the point, (x,y).

So `Atan2(0,1)` would be pi/2, or straight up (North).

That means the measurement starts with 0 being due East (right) and rotating counterclockwise.  It seems like you're expecting 0 deg. to be straight up and rotating clockwise, so you need to adjust your logic to reflect that.

Comment: So basicaly you are saying I should add 45 degrees to get it right?

Comment: No, the direction is reversed as well.  To convert to compass notation (0=N, 45=E, etc.), use `r2 = (90-r1) % 360`

Comment: But what are r1 and r2? Is r1 the rotation I have now and r2 the new one?

Comment: @DijkeMark Yes.  `r1` is the result of `ATan2` (cartesian angle), `r2` is the "compass" direction.

Comment: Strange, doesn't seem to work. When my mouse goes left, the object turns right and it also still doesn't point towards my mouse.

Comment: The weird thing is that I watched a tutorial on youtube with the same code and there it worked as supposed.

Comment: Where/how is _rotation used?  Does it rotate the object to that angle or is it relative?  (meaning a _rotation of 0 indicates no movement, a rotation of 90 indicates a quarter turn in one direction, etc.)

Comment: If you need to post more code to answer the last question, please edit your question vs. adding in a comment.  Much easier to read.

Comment: I added the code where _rotation is used. As you can see it is used directly as a parameter in the draw function in spriteBatch.Draw().

Comment: Do you think the problem could be caused by the fact that the object is an animation? I got a spritesheet and each so many frames it takes a different part of the spritesheet to show on the screen.

Comment: Looking at the docs for SpriteBatch.Draw, I see two things:  1) The angle should be in radians, not degrees, and 2) it is a rotation of the sprite from its original position, so a rotation of 0 will leave the sprite unchanged (which way it's "pointing" depends on the actual sprite) and a rotation of pi/2 will flip it horizontally.  Search MSDN for "rotating a sprite" for more info.

Comment: I really don't understand it anymore. Could you make a example of how the calculation should be then? No matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I found some kind of fix. The rotation is already in radians, so all I gotta do is rotate it 90 degrees to the right, which is 1.5 in radians. See edit 3 for the result.